# using Google BigQuery through Python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to make some very easy tasks on BigQuery via a python script. I found [this package](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) which does not work well. Indeed, when I try this code:

```
from bigquery import get_client


project_id = 'txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9'
# Service account email address as listed in the Google Developers Console.
service_account = '7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
# PKCS12 or PEM key provided by Google.
key = '/home/fxxxxxxxxxxxx/Dropbox/access_keys/google_storage/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem'
client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account, private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
# Submit an async query.
results = client.get_table_schema('newdataset', 'newtable2')

print('results')
```

I get this error:

```
/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/bin/python2.7 /home/xxxxxx/Dropbox/Prog/bigQuery_daily_import/src/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxxx/Dropbox/Prog/bigQuery_daily_import/src/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account, private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigquery/client.py", line 83, in get_client
    readonly=readonly)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bigquery/client.py", line 101, in _get_bq_service
    service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 196, in build
    cache)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 242, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 565, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 835, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 862, in _do_refresh_request
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1541, in _generate_refresh_request_body
    assertion = self._generate_assertion()
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1670, in _generate_assertion
    private_key, self.private_key_password), payload)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 121, in from_string
    pkey = RSA.importKey(parsed_pem_key)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 665, in importKey
    return self._importKeyDER(der)
  File "/home/xxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/snakes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 588, in _importKeyDER
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My question: is there a tutorial in python which shows how to communicate easily with BigQuery: importing a dataset from google storage or S3, querying something, exporting the result to google storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot depends on your environment, and once you've figure that out everything should be super simple. I see the only problem on the error log you pasted is figuring out authentication.

Python pandas has had support for BigQuery for a while:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq.html

And I did a video with the creators of the module:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLeTDUMb7HY

Now, the simplest and fastest way these days to launch an Jupyter notebook with all of the Google Cloud goodies you mention is our new Google Datalab project:

- https://cloud.google.com/datalab/

The only Datalab caveat is that it works on cloud servers, but if you want a fully managed Jupyter/IPython environment, totally secure, persistent, and ready to handle BigQuery, storage, etc... try it out.

---

Meanwhile, if you are writing a web application look at how other web applications solve this task.

For example, re:dash code to connect to BigQuery:

https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash/blob/master/redash/query_runner/big_query.py

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I want to build a web application, not explore some data with a jupyter like notebook. I am only looking for an equivalent of the packages boto or psycopg2 or sqlalchemy-redshift which works very well for redshift.

Comment: context helps a lot! check how re:dash does it https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash/blob/master/redash/query_runner/big_query.py

Comment: meanwhile I haven't tried sqlalchemy-bigquery, but since you mention using sqlalchemy: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy_bigquery/